# Salesforce Email Add-In for Einstein Activity Capture no showing Quick Actions

Tags: einstein-activity-capture

I just recently noticed a difference in the Salesforce Add-In for Gmail and Outlook.

I activated EAC on one of our developer Orgs in order to get some hands-on time with the new feature. I discovered if you deselect the email-automation in EAC you were able to get the "+"-Symbol and the Add-to-Salesforce Button back in the Add-In.

[image: Add-in with LS and EAC on Dev Org]

Today I activated EAC on a customer Sandbox to showcase the new feature and I was assuming that I could configure it the same way as on Dev-Org. I did so but to my agonie it seems they now have a migrate button and I could find a way to get the "+"-Symbol back.

[image: Add-in with EAC on Customer Sandbox]

Does anyone have an idea on how to get the "+"-Symbol back or is this a new "Feature" from Salesforce nobody asked for?

If I deactivate the EAC and only activate LS on Customer Sandbox the "+"-Symbol reappears.

Thanks in advance and I am also contacting Salesforce Support in Case there might be an adequate answer I will update this post.

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When I first activated the Lightning Sync I created a new Publisher Layout and it was assigned automatically. Afterwards I activated EAC and somehow without notice it unassigned all Profiles to none.

You need the Publisher Layout to be assigned to the profile you're using in order to get the "+"-Symbol aka Action Menu.

Also I found this article helpful [Link to SF Help Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000333870&type=1)!

Hopefully this will help someone too :)